# How to use a pre-installed Ubuntu, which is on an external drive to boot from any computer?

Tags: boot, grub2, bootloader, external-hdd, system-installation

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my external hard drive and it works fine on the computer it was originally installed from. But when I attempt to boot the external drive from another computer; all I get is black screen with a blinking underscore.

Do I have to install any similar application/service on each computer or to change anything with grub? I already know about the USB live CD but this is a full installation of Ubuntu that I want to boot,

Am I doing anything wrong or is there a possible way to succeed?

Comment: When does the blinking underscore happen? Does it get to the "try or install ubuntu" page?

Comment: It's already installed it's not a live CD or USB, it's a full instalation

Answer (score 0):

by no means an expert but I would assume that an "installed" Ubuntu is to an extend tailored to its HW. I can therefore see that moving the disk to other HW would lead to issues. I would likewise also expect that the Bootloader is very generic. So can you get to the bootloader screen e.g GRUB. If so I think that selecting recovery mode would then be your best try to see whether you can get some indication of what the machine is telling you when trying to boot.